# VBA code to initialize an Access form via Load event

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, onload-event

I have a form that I want to initialize with a record number when it loads. 
In a couple of other forms in my database I use code like the following with success:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim rstforf As DAO.Recordset, i As Integer, j As Integer
  Set rstforf = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TabForfatter", dbOpenDynaset)
  With rstforf
    ' find index
   .MoveFirst
   j = .Fields(0)
   Do Until .EOF
     If .Fields(0) = j Then .MoveNext Else Exit Do
     j = j + 1
   Loop
  ' insert the index in TabForfatter
  .AddNew
  .Fields(0) = j
  ' Write it on the form
   Me.ArtForfatter_id = j
   ' lock and disable the fiels
   Me.ArtForfatter_id.Locked = True
   Me.ArtForfatter_id.Enabled = False
 End With
 End Sub
```

When I try the same in the "problem form" it displays the first record its associated table with the record number found via the algorithm above. When I look at the associated table the record appears with the new number.

What I want is a blank form with just the record number and the rest to fill in manually, as is the case with the code example above.

When I code the piece for the problem form VBA does not give me the option to lock and disable the field. The manual says that only textboxes can be locked or disabled but in my code example the field is a number and it works.

I have tried DoCmd.GotoRecord with the record number found. It gives me a blank form but without the record number. .MoveLast followed by .MoveNext don't do the trick either.

Can somebody help?

Biørn Veirø

Comment: Is the form data-bound?  I.e., does it specify a `RecordSource`?

Comment: One thing I noticed, you never use `.Update` to commit your recordset change.  This might be impacting your expected outcome.

Comment: Yes! the form is data-bound because it does specify a data source.

Comment: The second note: while developing the code I tried to use .Update and got an error message. Therefore I assumed that the .Update was implied when I left the form

Comment: What happens if you use `Call DoCmd.GoToRecord(, , acNewRec)` just before you start working with the `ArtForfatter_id` field?

Comment: The code presented here does work with a form in my database called "FrmTilføjForfatter" (meaning FrmAddAuthor). The piece of code that does not work is as follows:

Comment: The code presented here does work with a form in my database called "FrmTilføjForfatter" (meaning FrmAddAuthor). The piece of code that does not work is for another form where the key is called ArtId. When I make the DoCmd.GoToRecord … I get a blank form with the correct record number in the record number box but with a 0 in the fiels called ArtId.

Comment: I am surprised if the code you show worked for other forms.  You should NOT both call `.AddNew` on the recordset opened in the function AND also set the value in the form.  A properly-designed Access form will automatically create a new record without having to call `.AddNew`.

Comment: By the way, why not use an AutoNumber column?  Is it really necessary to have continuous index numbers?  Or is this an artificial requirement just to satisfy the desire for "no gaps"?

Comment: You say *"When I code the piece for the problem form VBA does not give me the option to lock and disable the field."*  What do you mean by "does not give me the option"?  In the code you just type exactly what you have, so what is "an option"?  Do you mean it does not show in Intellisense popup?   Also, a number field is still usually bound to a TextBox control.  TextBox controls are not just for text data types--they are also controls for numbers and dates.

Comment: On your first comment, I will have to think a bit.

Comment: On your second comment: Yes,  it _is_  an artificial requirement. I don't use AutoNumber, because in the beginning of the development of my database it gave me a problem. Unfortunately I have forgotten, what it was. Your third comment: First I do Me.fieldname = indexfound. then I want to do Me.fieldname.Locked = True and Me.fieldname.Enabled = False. For other forms when I wrote the "." a long list of options appeared, but for the problem form I can only choose Me.fieldname.Value. If I enter the values I want anyway, I get a run-time -error

Comment: What do you mean by "a properly designed form"? I have read Jeff Conrads book "Microsoft Access 2013 Inside Out" to make my database. I am not sure, however, I have been able to follow all the instructions given. Can you provide another reference for form design?